# How to Make Gridview Header from table column values?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i would like to know how to make dynamic header for gridview using database column values.
for example i have two table like department and studentsdetails, the table values is as below
**department table**

```
id  |    name                     
1   |    CSE    
2   |    ECE
```

**studentdetails table**

```
id   | studentname |  email   |deptid   
1    | xxx         |  xx@com  | 1  
2    | yyy         |  yy@com  | 1  
3    | zzz         |  zz@com  | 2
```

i am `joing` above tables and show my result in `gridview like below

```
deptname | studentname | email     
CSE      | xxx         | xx@com   
CSE      | yyy         | yy@com   
ECE      | ZZZ         | zz@com
```

but i want to bind `gridview` with header like below. i want to make one column as header .

```
CSE                                                                                                                                                              
xxx | xx@com                        
YYY | yy@com                                  
ECE                                                          
zzz |zz@com
```

please help me to show `gridview` like above. please suggest me if anyone has better solution show my result like above structure.
Thank you.

Comment: your keyword is "Nested GridView"..

Answer (score 0):

You probably using `AutoGenerated` columns for the GridView. Switch to `TemplateField` for more control.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CSE">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("deptname") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="mailto:<%# Eval("email") %>"><%# Eval("email") %></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```